# Solve A Linear Congruence Using Euclid's Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Solve a Linear Congruence using Euclid's Algorithm
I'm just a bit confused by how to plug in the remainders and such.

$179x\cong355\pmod{937}$

$937=179\cdot5+42 \implies 42=937-179\cdot5$

$179=42\cdot4+11\implies11=179-42\cdot4$

$42=11\cdot3+9\implies9=42-11\cdot3$

$11=9\cdot1+2\implies2=11-9\cdot1$

$9=2\cdot4+1\implies1=9-4\cdot2$

Starting from the last remainder:

$1=9-4\cdot2$

Plugging in the $2$:

$=9-4(11-9\cdot1)$

$=9-4\cdot11+4\cdot9$

Somehow this simplifies to $5\cdot9-4\cdot11$?

I'm a bit confused on this all, it would be appreciated if someone could lend me a hand.

Answer (score 1):

> \begin{align}
> 1 &= 5(42-11(3))-4(11)\\
> &=5(42)-19(11) \\
> &= 5(42)-19(179-42(4)) \\
> &= 81(42)-19(179) \\
> &= 81(937-179(5))-19(179) \\
> &= 81(937) - 424(179) 
> \end{align}

You did it right. If you go all the way up, you can obtain

$$1=81(937)-424(179)$$

$$1 \equiv (-424)(179) \mod 937$$

Hence, I would multiply the linear congruent equation by $-424$.